# Running Cucumber JS in Browser

Tags: javascript, cucumber, bdd

Is there a way to run CucumberJS in the browser. I mean, without nodejs? I am hoping to find a way similar to the Jasmine standalone. http://pivotal.github.io/jasmine/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can. Please checkout this [example HTML code](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/blob/master/example/index.html) for basic ideas.

Here's the steps on how to run the example with node runtime:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js.git
$ cd cucumber-js/example
$ npm install
$ node server.js
```

Then open your browser and navigate to `http://localhost:9797/`, click the button **Run feature**. you should see the test result in green background.

Notice that the node is used to provide a web server to host all resources for your browser.

If you're interested in details, check out this [blog post](http://shawnzhu.blogspot.com/2014/03/use-cucumberjs-in-browser-without-node.html)

Comment: I upvoted but think this answer could be more detailed.

Comment: @user254694 updated my answer. and more details can be found from my blog post.

Answer (score 1):

I had, in the past, used the HTML example that @shawnzhu provided, but found the requirement to actually defined the features and steps in a script a disruption to my already current workflow of having features and steps (and support) in separate files.

As such, I create cucumberjs-browser CLI tool that bundles those files (using browserify) to be run in the browser using the browser-based CucumberJS library.

You can find the project here: https://github.com/bustardcelly/cucumberjs-browser

As well, I have a post about the available browser-based solutions: http://custardbelly.com/blog/blog-posts/2014/02/10/cucumberjs-tests-browser/index.html

Hope that helps.